# Nginx rewrite map with query strings

Tags: nginx, web-server, regex

I have a large rewrite-map.conf file which contains a number of redirects for a server however this does not work if there is a query string variable in the URL.

For example my /etc/nginx/conf.d/redirect-map.conf contains the following:

> map $request_uri $redirect_uri {
>   /docs/oldurlone /documents/newurlone
>   /docs/oldurltwo /documents/newurltwo
>   /docs/oldurlthree /documents/newurlthree
>   }

In my nginx server config I have the following config doing the redirect

> if ( $redirect_uri ) {
>   return 302 $redirect_uri;
>    }

So going to https://example.com/docs/oldurlone redirects nicely to https://example.com/documents/newurlone

My issue is that should the original url contain a query string also, I'd want that to get passed through.

If I entered:
https://example.com/docs/oldurlone/?affiliatenumber27&name=dave

then I would want this to pass through to
https://example.com/documents/newurlone/?affiliatenumber27&name=dave

I have a feeling I need to do some regex somewhere but I'm firstly not sure exactly where (eg which config file this needs going in).

If anyone can help me, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

as per NGINX docs, $request_uri does contain query string: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri

so you need to strip it before you pass it to your map:

```
map $request_uri $request_uri_path {
  "~^(?P<path>[^?]*)(\?.*)?$"  $path;
}
```

and then you can use your map as follows:

```
map $request_uri_path $redirect_uri {
/docs/oldurlone /documents/newurlone
/docs/oldurltwo /documents/newurltwo
/docs/oldurlthree /documents/newurlthree
}
```

see see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43749234/1246870 for the stripping args piece.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following:

```
if ( $redirect_uri ) {
    return 302 $redirect_uri$is_args$args;
}
```

If the map is not catching the request URI when it has an extra query parameter, then you need to capture it with a named regex and push it into the `$redirect_uri`, like so (I believe):

```
map $request_uri $redirect_uri {
    /docs/oldurlone(?<query>.*)$ /documents/newurlone$query
    /docs/oldurltwo(?<query>.*)$ /documents/newurltwo$query
    /docs/oldurlthree(?<query>.*)$ /documents/newurlthree$query
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately restarting nginx throws up the error that variable query is undefined. I tried the above but using  `(\?.*)` to match anything after a question mark and `$1` on the end of the redirect line eg as follows:  

`/docs/oldurltwo(\?.*) /documents/newurltwo$1`  

and also with the ~ to specifiy regex:  

`/docs/oldurltwo(\?.*) /documents/newurltwo$1`  

 but unfortunately this still didnt work.